# Recursive type definition inside a template

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I want to define multidimensional array with the help of variadic template as `vector<vector<....>>`, but stumbled upon impossibility to define type `initializer_list<initializer_list<...>>`, which is needed for initializer-list-constructor. This briefly can be demonstrated by the following code

```
template<class T, size_t dim>
class MyArr : vector < MyArr < T, dim - 1 >>
{
public:
    typedef initializer_list<MyArr < T, dim - 1 >::ListType> ListType;
    //using ListType = typename initializer_list<MyArr < T, dim - 1 >::ListType>;
};

template<class T>
class MyArr<T, 1> : vector < T>
{
public:
    typedef initializer_list<T> ListType;
};
```

Compiler displays "error C2923: 'std::initializer_list' : 'MyArr::ListType' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Elem'".

What is the right way to define `ListType` type?
Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything behind `MyArr<T, dim - 1>::` is a *dependent-name*, since both `T` and `dim` are template parameters, thus,  a `typename` keyword is necessary to indicate it is a type.

```
template<class T, size_t dim>
class MyArr : vector < MyArr < T, dim - 1 >>
{
public:
    typedef initializer_list<typename MyArr < T, dim - 1 >::ListType> ListType;
    //                       ^^^^^^^^
};
```

or:

```
template<class T, size_t dim>
class MyArr : vector < MyArr < T, dim - 1 >>
{
public:
    using ListType = initializer_list<typename MyArr < T, dim - 1 >::ListType>;
    //                                ^^^^^^^^
};
```

Comment: Yes, this works, thanks a lot. Still I don't understand the logic behind the placement of `typename`.

Comment: @AlexB. It comes immediately before something that you know is going to be a type, but that the compiler can't infer must be a type.  For example, if you specialized `MyArr<int, 2>` to have a `static int ListType` then in `MyArr<int, 3>`, `MyArr<T, dim - 1>` would not name a type.  Since `T` isn't known yet it doesn't know for sure if `ListType` is going to be a type.  You put `typename` before the whole thing to hint to the compiler that it should assume that it will be a type.

Comment: I don't see how the compiler can deduce `dim - 1`?